# Proposed tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I don't know whether people with the rep to vote on tag synonyms get notifications on proposal, or whether they have to look manually, so this is a notification that I've proposed two synonyms to bring together all date-related questions under [date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date). See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/date/synonyms

Comment: I'd vote, but I don't seem to have enough answer score for it. After manually retagging [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4106/is-it-christmas-code-golf) I _should_ have it, but apparently the system hasn't really registered it yet.  Anyway, given how few questions there are using the proposed synonyms, it might be easiest to just manually retag them all.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, fair comment on date-manipulation (I'll do it now), but people might well think of "calendar" when tagging a question and it won't auto-suggest "date".

Answer (score 1):

After hunting, I finally found a tag I'm eligible to vote on: [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) really ought be [shortest-time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortest-time).  I had no idea that it was up for synonymy until I clicked on [shortest-time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortest-time).

Thus, unless a user independently sees two synonymous tags and decides to register their synonymy, they'd never know another user thought the same.  Perhaps this warrants a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to either add tag synonyms to the review system, or to rubbish the reputation barrier until we have enough high-reputation users for it to work efficiently.

Comment: There _is_ a "[tag synonym review](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms)" page, it's just pretty hard to find. (The easiest way I know is to click on any tag, then "synonyms", then "see all tag synonyms".)